# rioBufferWrite function Redis updating position

Tags: c, redis

When I am reading the code of [`rio.c`](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/src/rio.c) in Redis, I find some confusing points about the `rioBufferWrite` and the `rioBufferRead` function. Why both the two functions need add `len` to `pos`?
I think only the read operation should update the `pos`. I will be very grateful for your answer.

Here is the code:

```
/* Returns 1 or 0 for success/failure. */
static size_t rioBufferWrite(rio *r, const void *buf, size_t len) {
    r->io.buffer.ptr = sdscatlen(r->io.buffer.ptr,(char*)buf,len);
    r->io.buffer.pos += len;
    return 1;
}

/* Returns 1 or 0 for success/failure. */
static size_t rioBufferRead(rio *r, void *buf, size_t len) {
    if (sdslen(r->io.buffer.ptr)-r->io.buffer.pos < len)
        return 0; /* not enough buffer to return len bytes. */
    memcpy(buf,r->io.buffer.ptr+r->io.buffer.pos,len);
    r->io.buffer.pos += len;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You could post the code as text

Comment: Did you try to paste these chinese symbols refering to updating pos in write function to translator ?

Comment: Why do you think only the read operation should update the position?

Comment: @AndreKampling I think that the read operation records the position where it finishes reading last time, so it need to update. But the write operation just append string to the buf. If it updates the position, when the next time I call the read operation, the pos is not correct.

Comment: In the [sources](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/src/rio.c) there is this function: `static off_t rioBufferTell(rio *r) { ... }` and the following comment about it: `/* Returns read/write position in buffer. */`. They want's it to be the position for both operations. It's a question about a design decision. As I haven't that code in an IDE it's hard to search for all occurrences of the position... I think that they need it at some point to be equal for both.

Comment: @AndreKampling Thanks very much for your answer! I check the code and understand that pos is used to 'return read/write position in buffer'. So the pos need to be sync.